# How can I stop the "setInterval" command when the number in a text is x?

Tags: javascript

a number increases automatically and when for example, this number becomes 50 , I want "setInterval" command to stop.

a different function will work in the background. This function will stop when the number reaches the x number.

The number is inside the "p" tag. How can I access and control it?

> < p > number < p class = "x"

Comment: use [clearInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach without the `interval` if interested :-

```js
const counterEle = document.querySelector('.counter');

function generateCount(limit,element){
element.innerText  = parseInt(element.innerText)+1;
if(element.innerText < limit){
setTimeout(generateCount,100,limit,element);
}
}

generateCount(50,counterEle);
```

```html
<p class='counter'>0</p>
```

Comment: The number is inside the "p" tag. How can I access and control it? -     < p > number < p class = "x"

Comment: Updated the snippet. For interval based approach, see @Alan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval);

```js
let number = 0;
const intervalId = setInterval(() => {
  number++
  console.log(number);
  if (number === 50) {
    clearInterval(intervalId);
  }
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

you mean you have something like `setinterval(() => {x+=1}, 1000)`? if so, change it to `y = setinterval(() => {x+=1; if (x == 50) { clearInterval(y); }}, 1000)`

Answer (score 1):

use `clearInterval` to delete the timer you created using `setInterval`:

```js
let title = document.getElementById("title")
let timer = 0
let timerId = setInterval(() => {
    if(timer === 10)
      clearInterval(timerId)
    title.textContent=timer++
  },500)
```

```html
<h2 id = "title"></h2>
```